# Class file access to WPF control like code behinde

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I have three files with myfile.xaml, myfile.xaml.cs and one another class name: myclass.cs.

Is it possible or not to combine that three files can be access each other.

What I want is , I want myclass.css can access all WPF control like a code behinde (myfile.xaml.cs), I was spend for 2 days, but still useless, So I really need someone answer my question, if you know about this problem.

Help me please!

Comment: 1. What are you trying to accomplish by that? 2. What exactly do you mean by "accessing all WPF control"?

Comment: Partial Class it? Pass the control in?

Comment: Use Databinding, maybe using any MVVM pattern. If not, you'll be completely out of the WPF philosophy (and you'll have hard time to maintain the app)

Answer (score 0):

What does this `myclass.cs` do? Perhaps it shouldn't access those WPF controls directly at all. Implementing some  events in it and then binding the window to those events could a better, cleaner and more maintainable approach.

Simple, compilable example:

`MyClass.cs`

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    // this class does not know anything about the window directly
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            if (OnSendMessage != null) // is anybody listening?
            {
                OnSendMessage("I'm sending a message"); // i don't know and i don't care where it will go
            }
        }

        public event SendMessageDelegate OnSendMessage; // anyone can subscribe to this event
    }

    public delegate void SendMessageDelegate(string message); // what is the event handler method supposed to look like? 
    // it's supposed to return nothing (void) and to accept one string argument
}
```

`Window1.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="tbMessage" /> <!-- just a textbox -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Window1.xaml.cs` (code-behind file)

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.OnSendMessage += new SendMessageDelegate(myClass_OnSendMessage); // subscribing to the event

            myClass.DoSomething(); // this will call the event handler and display the message in the textbox.

            // we subscribed to the event. MyClass doesn't need to know anything about the textbox.
        }

        // event handler
        void myClass_OnSendMessage(string message)
        {
            tbMessage.Text = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: myclass.css do such as add item into listbox control in myfile.xaml

Actually, if I write in code behinde(myfile.xaml.cs) is ok, but what I want is myclass.css can access to myfile.xaml all events,

Example: add items then selectionChange when selectedItem like window form use selectIndexChange.

Comment: Why does it do that? What does `myclass` represent? A list of users or products, for example? In that case this class is a `model`, and it shouldn't care about displaying data. A class should only have one responsibility. Being a container for data is one responsibility. Displaying it is another. It's called separation of concerns. Even if you only just started learning - learn it the right way from the beginning. It'll be more painful later on, believe me.

Comment: `Example: add items then selectionChange when selectedItem like window form use selectIndexChange.` - incomprehensible for me, I'm sorry

Comment: Thanks for your answer , it is almost match to what I want, but I want to ask you one more question, Can I delegate Event selectionChange (ListBox) from myclass.cs like a text message in Window1.xaml.cs (code-behind file)?

What I do is , I was add Item in myclass.css, not add Item in code-behind file, but the problem when I select the Item added, It's not work, because ListBox control cannot access from myclass.cs directly,but code-behind only